# $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, $A(I_2-A)=I_2 \Rightarrow A^2-I_2$ is invertible

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I've been asked to either prove or disprove that for a 2 by 2 matrix $A$ and the 2 by 2 identity matrix $I$, if $A(I-A) = I$ then $A^2-I$ is invertible.

To detail what I've attempted so far, if necessary:
I started by trying to find a counterexample to no avail, so I tried to prove it; but that also didn't quite work out. The things I did show (assuming no silly mistakes were made) are:

1. $A$ is invertible, and $A^{-1}=I-A$, which results directly from $A(I-A)=I$ by the definition of matrix invertibility (so $I-A$ is also invertible).
2. $A^2 = A-I = -A^{-1}$ through left distributivity.
3. $A^3 = -I$, stemming directly from #2 by right-multiplying both sides by $A$.
4. $A^2-I = A-2I = (A+I)(A-I)$, using #2 (left side to middle) and left & right distributivity (right side to left side).

As for #4, which feels significant because it involves the expression I'm investigating, I already know that $(A-I) = A^2$ which is invertible (because $A$ is, and also because of #2 above), so I could "reduce" the problem to proving that $A+I$ is invertible because then $(A^2-I)\cdot((-A)\cdot(A+I)^{-1})=I$ and we're done; but I couldn't find a way to do that, either.

Would greatly appreciate some assistance or a nice hint :)

Comment: Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(A+I)x=0$ then $A^{2}x=A(-x)=-Ax=x$ and  $A(I-A)x=Ax-A^{2}x=-x-x=-2x$. By hypothesis this implies that $x=0$ so the kernel of $A+I$ is $\{0\}$. Hence $A+I$ is invertible. Also $det (A(I-A))=1$ so $det (A) \neq 0$ and $det (I-A) \neq 0$. It follows now that $A-I$ and $A+I$ are both invertible. Hence $A^{2}-I=(A-I)(A+I)$ is also invertible.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that; that's a really neat way of looking at it, turning it into a homogenous system of equations to prove invertibility!
I've only recently looked at determinants so I'm a bit less clear on the second point. Would you mind expanding a tiny bit on why it follows that $A+I$ is also invertible from the points you've made?

Comment: A linear transformation on $\mathbb R^{n}$ is invertible if and only if it is injective (if and only if it is surjective)  if and only if its kernel is $\{0\}$.  @ShyGuy

Comment: Sorry; what I meant to ask is not about the transformation & kernel from the first part (I'm clear on that one, I believe), but rather why $det(A) \ne 0 \wedge det(I-A) \ne 0 \Rightarrow A+I$ is invertible. (Hopefully I didn't just misunderstand your answer just now!)

Comment: @ShyGuy I proved that $(A+I)x=0$ implies $x=0$. This means $I+A$ is injective , hence invertible. I did not use determinants in this part.  (I used determinants later to show that $I-A$ is invertible).

Comment: Ahhh, I see; I thought the second part was like a different apprpoach to it (I built upon the first part of your post in my proof by using your proof of $A+I$'s invertibility in conjunction with the one I noted in my post, i.e that $A-I$ is invertible because $A$ is known to be its inverse). Thanks again, really appreciate it!